# rmarkdown and emphasizing significate values with bold text or color

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to bold emphasize values that are under p<-.05 in the tables or mark it with a different color in the table. How can I achieve that in RMARDOWN?

Sample code is

````
---
title: "Kable output"
output: html_document
---
```{r printing,echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, warning =     FALSE,cache=FALSE, results='asis'}


library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom)


kbl <- function (df) {
  cat("\n\n")
  df2<-kable(df) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options =     c("striped", "condensed"))
  print(df2)
  cat("\n\n")
}


df <- mtcars
nested_inter <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest() ## groups all the data by the sub series
nested_inter <- nested_inter  %>% 
  mutate (model =  map(data, 
                       ~lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + drat + hp     +wt , data = .)))


for(i in seq(nrow(nested_inter))) {
  kbl(glance(nested_inter$model[[i]]))
  t1<- nested_inter$model[[i]] %>% broom::tidy() 
  kbl(t1)
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the chunk options include `results='asis'`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(broom)

mtcars %>% 
  arrange(gear) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest() %>%  
  mutate(df =  map(data, lm, formula = mpg ~ cyl + drat ) %>% 
            map(broom::tidy),
          tb = pmap(list(x = df, 
                         caption = paste("Gears = ", gear)), 
                    .f = kbl, 
                    digits = 2) %>% 
           map(kable_styling, 
               bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed")),
         formatted_tb = map2(tb, df, function(tb, df) {
           column_spec(tb, 
                       column = 5, 
                       bold = map_lgl(df$p.value, 
                                  function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x), 
                                                     FALSE, 
                                                     x < 0.05)))})) %>% 
  pull(formatted_tb) %>% 
  walk(cat)
```

[image]